# features recognition & reconstruction of 3d mesh delaunay matlab

Tags: matlab, mesh-generation, delaunay-triangulation

I managed to display the coordinates of x,y and z into a 3D mesh by using delaunay function. The coordinates are in .obj format actually and i have read it into matrix form.

Now, i would like to extract certain features / regions from the 3D mesh, reconstruct a new mesh and get the coordinates of it (I would like to extract specific ROI or volume of interest (VOI) form the mesh).

For example:

A 3D facial image mapped into triangular mesh, and i want to extract the nose region. the same method cam be used as template for other data.

Is it possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Jueru, and welcome to scicomp!  Do you have a predefined surface mesh around the *entire* boundary your region of interest?

Comment: I always cringe when people say they're working with meshes in Matlab. There are better tools out there, like CAD programs and actual meshing programs. A nice tool is [Meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Hi @Paul. Yes, i think so. It's a mesh of human face.